# Which system configuration is best for iPhone application develoment?

Tags: iphone, xcode, configuration

I want to develop iPhone application using XCode IDE. Anyone tell me the which system configuration is best for iPhone developing? What all are the requirements to be want for iPhone development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as it's an Intel Mac running Snow Leopard (10.6.x) you should be fine, although I'd recommend at least 1GB and ideally 2GB of RAM.

That said, you've asked for the "best", which would obviously be the top of the line Mac Pro fully stacked with RAM, a RAID card, etc. and with dual 27" Cinema Displays. However, you'll still have to wait just as long to squirt your app down a USB cable into the device for testing. :-)

Comment: 1 GB is definitely not enough to run XCode properly. 2+ GB, and I recommend 4. It's a memory hungry, CPU eating, bug loaded, IDE.

Comment: @MIRAGe - I've run XCode perfectly well in 1GB.

Comment: I even have trouble with my new mac book, I guess it depends on what you think is 'perfectly well' and how big your project actually is.

Answer (score 3):

I've started iPhone development with a MacBook. It's certainly fast enough and has served me well.

But its display with a resolution of 1280 by 800 pixels is no longer big enough to display the iPhone simulator since iPhone 4 with its higher resolution of 640 by 960 pixel was introduced.

I've now connected it to an external display.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably run XCode on any Intel based mac running Snow Leopard.
At least 2GB of RAM is recommended but not a must.

(And don't forget that if you want to upload your app to the appstore or test on a device you need to join Apple  developer program which will cost you 100$ a year)